# Is there any real use case of using of Complex Event Processing (esp. Drools)?

Tags: java, drools, complex-event-processing, business-rules, redhat-brms

I want to find some problem (use case) in the sphere of [Complex Event Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) to solve it and implement the solution on [Drools](https://www.drools.org/).
I will be glad to read any advice. It is needed for my graduate work. 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you think we should rack some search engine for you?

Comment: I have not found any real problems while I searched. That why I ask people about their ideas

Answer (score 0):

E.g.: Fraud detection, Trading and financial services, Smart Home, IoT, Predictive Maintenance, Complement ML models with declarative logic, ...

You stated you didn't find any real problem while you searched but that sound very strange to me as thesis and books on subject do mention use-cases.